# How to push uiviewcontroller over tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar app. each tab has uinavigationcontroller. but all navigationcontroller's Shows Navigation Bar value is NO.

i control the which navgation control is active in

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

event in AppDelegate. Then i the user taps a row in a table in a tab i call the same method (openDetail)in appdelegate. i want to push DetailViewController full screen, not in tabs controller. i tried some ways but never worked. so i push it as a modalview.

```
[currentNavController presentModalViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

how can it come/go from right side. 
i just want it to work like normal rootviewcontroller. but new controller should come over tabbarcontroller like USA Today app.

Answer (score 3):

present the view controller like this

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: i think u misunderstood me. i dont want to display it as modalview. modalview comes from bottom or fliphorizontal. i want it comes from right side as normal pushview.

Comment: i found it.detailVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; then pushview.